# Change website URL in IIS

Tags: url, iis, iis-7.5

I have a site set up in IIS that I'm currently accessing via localhost, I'd like to access it via URL mysite instead for example... I have edited the binding in IIS to add mysite as a host, and have also added the line 127.0.0.1 mysite to the hosts file. When I try and access mysite via a browser it seems to be trying to go to the correct location but keeps requesting a username and password and won't accept the one I am logged on with (Windows Authentication is enabled in IIS).

Is there another setting somewhere that I need to change?

Thanks

Comment: If your application loads under localhost:80/ then this should just be a matter of editing your hosts file, you shouldn't need to change anything in IIS if it already deploys fine.  You've definitely changed C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts?  Could you provide this file?

Answer (score 0):

Check the authentication in IIS for the site. It should be "Windows Authentication".

In addition, you can also check the IE settings for Local Intranet. It should be set to "Automatic logon with current user name and password" or "Automatic logon only in Intranet zone".

Comment: All those settings are already on. Hosts file -

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1 mystuff